# How to handle multiple date format in Bsdatepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

what i need

- i need to handle multiple date format in bsdatepicker.

Date Component

```
        import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

        import * as moment from 'moment';
        import { BsDatepickerConfig, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
        @Component({
          selector: 'date',
          changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
          template: `
              <div [formGroup]="form" >
                <ng-container *ngIf="field.read_only !== 'Y'">
                    <div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode-field" 
                        bsDatepicker
                        [formControlName]="field.code"
                        [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"
                        [(ngModel)]="myDateValue"
                        (ngModelChange)="customOnDateChange($event);"
                        placeholder={{'DD-MMM-YYYY'}} 
                        #dp="bsDatepicker"
                        (keyup)="dp.toggle()"
                        value="{{ myDateValue | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}"
                        [(bsValue)]="myDateValue"
                       />
                        <i (click)="dp.toggle()"  class="far fa-calendar-alt date-field-calendar-icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="view-mode-field">{{ field.value }}</span>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="field.read_only === 'Y'">
                      <span class="">{{ field.value }}</span>
                </ng-container>
              </div>
            `
        })
        export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
          @Input() field: any = {};
          @Input() form: FormGroup;
          @Input() type: string;

          appConstants = new ClientAppConstants();

          get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.field.code].valid; }
          get isDirty() { return this.form.controls[this.field.code].dirty; }

          datePickerConfig = {
            isAnimated: true,
            containerClass: 'theme-blue',
            showWeekNumbers: false,
          };
          customInitDate = '';
          myDateValue = '';
          formatsDateFormats: any;
          constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private bs: BsDatepickerConfig) {
            this.formatsDateFormats = [
              'dd/MM/yyyy',
              'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
              'dd-MM-yyyy',
              'DD-MM-YYYY',
              'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',
              'MM/dd/yyyy',
              'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
              'yyyy/MM/dd',
              'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss',
              'dd/MM/yy',
              'dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss',
              'DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate', 'medium',
              'short', 'fullDate', 'longDate', 'mediumDate', 'mediumTime', 'DD-MMM-YYYY', 'YYYY-MMM-DD', 'YYYY/MMM/DD',
              'YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY/MM/DD'
            ];
            this.bs.dateInputFormat = this.formatsDateFormats;
          }
          ngOnInit() {
            if (this.field.value) {
              this.myDateValue = moment(new Date(this.field.value)).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
            }

            if (typeof this.field.maxDays != 'undefined') {
              const date1 = new Date();
              date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + this.field.maxDays);
              this.datePickerConfig['maxDate'] = date1;
            }
            if (typeof this.field.minDays != 'undefined') {
              const date2 = new Date();
              date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - this.field.minDays);
              this.datePickerConfig['minDate'] = date2;
            }
            this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path
            this.cd.detectChanges();
          }

          customOnDateChange(search: any) {
            if (search !== '') {
              if (moment(search).isValid()) {
                this.myDateValue = moment(new Date(search)).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
              } else {
                this.myDateValue = '';
              }

            }

          }

        }
```

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-testing?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: And who would switch between those? Or how would the datepicker know which one to use? I think this datepicker doesn't have the feature where a single instance can have multiple formats. Eg. see https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/datepicker/bs-datepicker.config.ts#L79 where the type of the `dateInputFormat` field is a single string. I think you can only configure _different instances_ of the datepicker to use different date formats, for that see the docs at https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: thanks for the hint . i need to handle different date format in texbox https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format

Comment: i need when user type any format it must be converted to dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: Please read the documentation. Here's the section about the format: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format

Comment: i already used   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY' } but it will work single date format.  how can bsdatepicker handle if i used DD/MM/YYYY then it will not work

Comment: that's why i used   constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private bs: BsDatepickerConfig,
        private localeService: BsLocaleService) {
        this.formats = ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate','medium',
        'short','fullDate','longDate','mediumDate', 'mediumTime','DD-MMM-YYYY'];
        this.bs.dateInputFormat = this.formats;

      }

Comment: but bsdatepicker lib failing format.replace is not a function

Comment: Please post your whole code in the original question, and this time with proper indentation and syntax highlight.

Comment: i also get error  RROR TypeError: format.match is not a function
    at makeFormatFunction (vendor.js:89717)
    at formatMoment (vendor.js:93705)
    at formatDate (vendor.js:93683)
    at BsDatepickerInputDirective.push../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/fesm5/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js.BsDatepickerInputDirective._setInputValue (vendor.js:102550)
    at vendor.js:102523
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (vendor.js:37345)
    at 
    at

Comment: can you suggest other datepicker which would handle my usecase

Comment: So with this line `this.bs.dateInputFormat = this.formatsDateFormats;` **you still pass an array to the datepicker, where it expets a single string**. Why is that? Other than that, I think I don't have any further ideas.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help, i need to achive search date by 10/9/1989 to be converted to 10-SEP-1989.  i was thinking user can type multiple date format in textbox or 10-SEP-1989 TO 10-Sep-1989

Comment: BsDatepickerDirective {_config: {…}, placement: "bottom", triggers: "click", outsideClick: true, container: "body", …}
isOpen: (...)
_config:
adaptivePosition: false
isAnimated: true
containerClass: "theme-blue"
displayMonths: 1
showWeekNumbers: false
dateInputFormat: "DD-MMM-YYYY"  if there is single date format i have no problem in handling it.